# Difference between df.where( ) and df [ (df [ ] == ) ] in pandas , python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Can Any I help me in telling the difference between these two statements in pandas - python

```
df.where(df['colname'] == value)
```

and

```
df[(df['colname'] == value)]
```

Why Am I getting different sizes in the output dataframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation of `where`:

> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

So the purpose of `where` is slightly different than filtering with brackets, as it will give you the result with the same shape of the dataframe you run it against.

The goal is in the notes of the documentation:

> The where method is an application of the if-then idiom. For each
>   element in the calling DataFrame, if `cond` is `True` the element
>   is used; otherwise the corresponding element from the DataFrame
>   `other` is used

Answer (score 0):

to get `true` `false` from `where` you need to do (as of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) ):

```
md= np.array([[2.49892703, 0.11392389],
        [1.05816512,0.30363405],
        [0.7192157,0.39640129],
        [1.05816512,0.30363405],
        [7.11076538,0.00766224],
        [0.7192157, 0.39640129],
        [1.05816512,0.30363405],
        [1.05816512,0.30363405],
        [0.7192157, 0.39640129]])
df0=  pd.DataFrame(md,columns=['md',  'p'])
print(df0)

cond= df0['p']<0.01
df0['out']= df0['p'].where(cond, "False") != np.where(cond, df0['p'], "False")
print(df0)
```