# Pandas DataFrame - What's the different between df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50] and df.where(df['SUMLEV'] == 50)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What's the different between `df[df['SUMLEV'] == 50]` and `df.where(df['SUMLEV'] == 50)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this answer help? [Difference between df.where( ) and df \[ (df \[ \] == ) \] in pandas , python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332974/difference-between-df-where-and-df-df-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 1):

`df[df['SUMLEV'].eq(50)]` returns a **subset** of the original DataFrame; the rows where your condition is `True`.

`df.where(df['SUMLEV'].eq(50))` returns a DataFrame **the same shape** as your original; rows where your condition evaluates to `False` are `NaN`'d out.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': [1,2,3,4], 'SUMLEV': [10,50,50,70]})

df[df['SUMLEV'].eq(50)]
#   foo  SUMLEV
#1    2      50
#2    3      50

df.where(df['SUMLEV'].eq(50))
#   foo  SUMLEV
#0  NaN     NaN
#1  2.0    50.0
#2  3.0    50.0
#3  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Ty you are awesome!